# Store country names in ISO 3166 format in mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npm

In my flight booking application the admin enters destination names while adding new flights. The admin can write the full country/City names (i.e. Sydney, New York etc.) But I want to save them as 3 letter abbreviation such as (SYD, NYC etc.) in the database when admin clicks the submit button. I tried using the `i18n-iso-countries` package but I'm not quite sure of implementing this. Is there any simple approach to this?

This is my form component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  TextField,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  RadioGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Radio,
  Button,
} from "@mui/material";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";
import "./Form.css";

const destinations = [
  { title: "Sydney" },
  { title: "Paris" },
  { title: "Thailand" },
  { title: "France" },
  { title: "Dhaka" },
  { title: "Bangkok" },
  { title: "Indonesia" },
];

export default function Form() {
  const dt = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  console.log(dt);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    from: "",
    to: "",
    depart: dt,
    return: dt,
    noOfPassenger: 1,
    tripType: "Round Trip",
  });

  const defaultProps = {
    options: destinations,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title,
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (formData.tripType === "One Way")
      setFormData({ ...formData, return: "None" });
    console.log(formData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="form_parent">
      <div className="inner_form">
        <div className="from">
          <Autocomplete
            {...defaultProps}
            onChange={(event, value) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, from: value.title })
            }
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="From" variant="outlined" required />
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="to">
          <Autocomplete
            {...defaultProps}
            onChange={(event, value) =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, to: value.title })
            }
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="To" variant="outlined" required />
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="dates">
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
              label="Departure Date"
              value={formData.depart}
              disablePast
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormData({
                  ...formData,
                  depart: e.toLocaleDateString(),
                })
              }
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required />}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </div>
        <div className="dates">
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
              label="Return Date"
              value={formData.return}
              disablePast
              disabled={formData.tripType === "One Way" ? true : false}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormData({
                  ...formData,
                  return: e.toLocaleDateString(),
                })
              }
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </div>
        <div className="dates">
          <FormControl className="passenger">
            <InputLabel id="passengerNo">No. of Passenger</InputLabel>
            <Select
              variant="outlined"
              labelId="passengerNo"
              value={formData.noOfPassenger}
              required
              label="No. of Passenger"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormData({ ...formData, noOfPassenger: e.target.value })
              }
            >
              <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={4}>4</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="radio_buttons">
          <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <RadioGroup
              row
              aria-label="trip"
              name="row-radio-buttons-group"
              value={formData.tripType}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormData({ ...formData, tripType: e.target.value })
              }
            >
              <FormControlLabel
                value="One Way"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="One Way"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="Round Trip"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="Round Trip"
              />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="submit">
          <Button
            className="submit_btn"
            variant="contained"
            color="error"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            endIcon={<SendIcon />}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Model**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const flightSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  from: String,
  to: String,
  price: String,
  flightType: String,
  airline: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
  },
});

const FlightData = mongoose.model("FlightData", flightSchema);

export default FlightData;
```

Comment: Why dong you add to `destinations` the short ISO name?

Comment: @balderman I wanted to make the application as user friendly as possible. Sometimes it becomes hard for the end user to remember all the abbreviations. That's why I'm trying to implement this approach.

Comment: I assume that the code is generation `<option>` HTML. If that is true - you can have a visual value is option and a logical value as well. The ISO name will be used as the logical value.See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: @balderman in this approach I have to add 196 options if the admin wants to provide service all over the world. Wouldn't it make the code more big? I don't want to approach in this way if there's easy solution.